# How to Calculate Cummulative Average by Filtering Latest Day for Similar Data Group from a Data Log File in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a log file that records all data for each User and each skill. The file is updated each time a user revises their skills. Data_Log_Table records all data (see image below) and I want to create a table that displays monthly average performance by taking the cumulative data to end of that month by taking only the last date data for identical Skill_ID.

For instance; UserID:1,Skill_ID:1

I want to exclude first row data during calculation, because there is another data later than this date for same month.

[image]

Comment: do you have a calendar/date table in your model?

Comment: Yes I have one calendar/date table in my model